# How can I check if the column has changed inside the struct array

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I'm using gorm as a Golang ORM. I need to detect is_active field has changed to trigger a update on a thirdy-party API service.

Here is my struct:

```
type MyProduct struct {
     ...
     MyVariants   []Variants

}
```

*Variants* type has **IsActive** column.I want to check *IsActive* column has changed or not of the all elements of the MyVariants array. I want to do this in BeforeUpdate or AfterUpdate Hooks.